# lastpage for french

Tags: french, lastpage

Does someone know, why the package lastpage doesn't work for french?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{french}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{lastpage}

\fancypagestyle{mine}{ %
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyfoot[LO]{\thepage\ sur \pageref{LastPage}}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{mine}

\newpage

bla
\end{document}
```

I get the error: \clearpage undefined. \end{document}

Comment: `fancyhdr` and a KOMA class is a bad idea ... but I think, you use `\usepackage[french]{babel}` and the appropiate fontencoding/inputencoding

Comment: The class `scrbook` is the problem, the `french` package has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Why do you use the package french instead of `\usepackage[french]{babel}`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Because I need babel v3.9i for this, and I can't upgrade it due to some administrator rights..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently `french.sty` defined a patch to cope with `lastpage`, but a change in the latter package makes the thing break.

You can use `zref`, instead:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{french}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{zref-user,zref-lastpage}

\fancypagestyle{mine}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[LO]{\thepage\ sur \zpageref{LastPage}}%
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{mine}
abc
\newpage

bla
\end{document}
```

Note that `utf8x` is not recommended nowadays. Also `fancyhdr` is not recommended with koma-script classes, but it still works.